# Multicast sockets packet loss

Tags: c, sockets, networking, multicast

I wrote simple multicast server and client program in C programming language. Then I connected server to the multicast enabled router (dd-wrt supported )via ethernet interface. Client is connected to the router via wireless interface. I'm sending packets from the server to the client every 10 ms. Packet size is 512 bytes. The problem is that client receive just 40% of packets which I can see also in Wireshark. This is not problem with wireless and packet loss , it is something about multicast and I can not figure out where is the problem. I also checked data rates and everything seems ok. Any advice? Thx

Comment: Depends on how you are generating packets.. and most obvious UDP packet losses are due to buffer overflow.

Comment: And what can I do to fix the buffer overflow? Packets are char[512] which are sent with sendto function

Comment: You will need to set SO_RCVBUF option in receiver socket. But, without seeing code, I cannot say sure.

Comment: The code is huge but I can copy part that you are interested in , just tell me which part and on which side: server or client

Comment: On which value should I set SO_RCVBUF at the client? How do I count buffer?

Comment: How many clients does receive multicast packets? What is the speed of wireless interface? What is happend when the server sends packets every 100ms?  Could you show more data about network and packet?

Comment: It seems more like programming bug in server. If you are sending only 1 packet of 512 bytes at every 10 ms, then I dont think it can be buffer overflow problems. Most likely, you are not transmitting packets at every 10 ms from server, but at duration greater than this. It can happen if you try to sleep server process in relative times.

Comment: There will be three clients but right now I'm testing just with one client to figure out where is the problem. Speed of wireless link is about 5 MB/sec and I'm sending 100 packets every 10 ms which is  0.04883 MB/sec . Server is connected to the router via ethernet with speed of 10 MB/ sec. At server side everything seems fine and I can see all packets that server sent out in the Wireshark. Problem is at the client side because it receives only 40% of packets.

Comment: Which operating system you are using at client?

Comment: Try to set UDP receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) size using function: "setsockopt" function, at client.

Comment: The client with which I test uses Windows OS, but I also have 2 more clients with Linux OS but I havent tried there, should I ? Ok I saw how to use SO_RCVBUF , but I need help how to calulate buffer size

Comment: @user3852803: just try a big buffer, like 4 MB or something.

Comment: I set int buffer_size = 4200000; and then use setsockopt with SO_RCVBUF at the client side, but still for the big packets like 1400 bytes (without fragmentation) packet loss is about 50% ....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Multicast runs over UDP. UDP has zero features for packet loss recovery. What you are seeing is endemic. If you want reliability you have to build it yourself.

Comment: Yes I know. I have also built retransmission mechanism. But this problem of packet loss is not because UDP reliability or wireless link, it is something else probably with buffer size or some other parameter. Now I tested again my system, when packets are small enough packet loss is also small, about 2%. Then I increase packet size to the 1400 bytes and I got packet loss 50 % (1400 bytes works without fragmentation). Then I used setsockopt function and set buffer size to the 65 000 but still I have packet loss about 40 % which is not because UDP reliability. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: set more UDP buffer.. like 2000 000. around 2 MB.

Comment: The generally accepted limit for UDP payload size is 534 bytes. That won't be fragmented, so the packet can only be lost in its entirety. Once fragmentation occurs, loss of any fragment implies loss of the whole.

Comment: I set int buffer_size = 4200000; and then use setsockopt with SO_RCVBUF at the client side, but still for the big packets like 1400 bytes (without fragmentation which I see when wireshark is turned on) packet loss is about 50% ....any ideas?

Comment: The idea is to use packets smaller than the path MTU. 534 is generally accepted.

Comment: EJP I saw that you already answered to his question about packet size, but I'm not sure why not 1400 bytes because I can see that fragmentation doesn't happen?